# How to call built-in api l2tp/ipsec on mac osx by application

Tags: macos, ipsec

I know that Mac OSX have supported ipsec conenection. So I want to start up ipsec connection in my app by calling built-in api on mac system.

how can I call this api? or can not do that?

please help me!

thanks!